parpool MATLAB running in the command-line on a slurm cluster
I've been running a matlab script in a cluster and I got a warning saying that my MATLAB programm was comsuming in excess 500% CPU, so somehow the MATLAB access the head-node.
I've been submitting my jobs by running the command "sbatch myJob.batch", where myJob.batch is the following script:
I would appreciate any help.
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -J 9h_11h_6g_c_windowing_blur_overload
#SBATCH -o %x.o%j   # output file name
#SBATCH -e %x.e%j   # error file name
#SBATCH -p 
#SBATCH -q standard
#SBATCH -n 8        # number of cores
#SBATCH -N 1        # number of nodes (use 1)
#SBATCH --mem=30G   # allocated memory
#SBATCH -t 07-00:00:00  # allocated wall time
#SBATCH --tmp=1GB   # allocated disk space
#SBATCH --mail-type=BEGIN,END   # notification type
#SBATCH --mail-user=

# load matlab module
module load matlab

# run matlab file
matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -r "PulseReconstruction; exit;"

I'm suspecting that the problem is on using parpool in MATLAB, which somehow might access the command-line on the cluster.
This is how I'm requesting parallel pool on matlab:
if isempty(gcp('nocreate'))
    parpool;
end
disp(gcp('nocreate'));

And this is my output from it:
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'Processes' profile ...
Connected to parallel pool with 8 workers.
 ProcessPool with properties: 
s
            Connected: true
           NumWorkers: 8
                 Busy: false
              Cluster: Processes (Local Cluster)
        AttachedFiles: {}
    AutoAddClientPath: true
            FileStore: [1x1 parallel.FileStore]
           ValueStore: [1x1 parallel.ValueStore]
          IdleTimeout: 30 minutes (30 minutes remaining)
          SpmdEnabled: true


Ask the cluster’s staff. They should know how they configured MATLAB and how you should run it properly on their cluster. Those people are there to help their users use their system, they want you to ask for their help.

By the way, use the -batch option in MATLAB, -r is outdated. matlab -batch PulseReconstruction (no exit or other options needed).

You're running a MATLAB client and a parallel pool there. By default, the MATLAB client will use up to maxNumCompThreads computational threads, and that's also the number of parallel workers you're launching. So you could easily be using twice as much processor as you've been allocated.
I suggest using
matlab -singleCompThread -batch PulseReconstruction

The other option is to use MATLAB Parallel Server on your cluster so that you run the workers directly there without needing the "client" to run on the cluster too.
